# HTML 5 AUDIO - Do I need audio.load() or can I just play()?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I read a post called [Don't forget to load() before you play()](http://softwareas.com/audiovideo-tag-dont-forget-to-load-before-you-play/)

This post if very old however and I wonder if it's still valid.  It says to structure your code like this

```
 audio.src = url;
 audio.load(); 
 audio.play();
```

It says when you change your source, you need to LOAD before you play.  If I leave out the load part and just change my source and play it, it works fine.  Is load something that is still used?

Comment: [audio play from javascript link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-play-audio-files-on-Javascript) `maybe this link will give your question's answer. according to my understanding just play() would be fine`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do `audio.play();` unless you want to load the full audio to the user's computer instead of streaming it which then you would use `audio.load();` and then `audio.play()`